# Passing struct composites into function

Tags: go, inheritance, composition

Need some help understanding golang.

Coming from C++ using a base class this is trivial. In Go, using struct composition, which works fine up to the point where I need to have function that take the "Base" struct. I understand that it's not truly a base class, but when comes to assigning values to the fields of the base class from the derived, it works fine. But I cannot pass `Dog` into a function that takes `Wolf`.

```
package main
    
import "fmt"
    
type Wolf struct {
    ID     string
    Schema int
}
    
type Dog struct {
    Wolf
}
    
type Dingo struct {
    Wolf
}
    
func processWolf(wolf Wolf) {
    fmt.Println(wolf.ID, wolf.Schema)
}
    
func main() {
    porthos := Dog{}
    porthos.ID = "Porthos"  // works fine able to set field of Wolf
    porthos.Schema = 1      // works fine
    
    aussie := Dingo{}
    aussie.ID = "Aussie"  // works fine
    aussie.Schema = 1     // works fine
    
    fmt.Println(porthos.ID, porthos.Schema)
    fmt.Println(aussie.ID, aussie.Schema)

    processWolf(porthos) << fails here
    processWolf(aussie) << fails here
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `processWolf` function takes a `Wolf` argument, so you have to pass a `Wolf`. Since both structures have `Wolf` embedded in them, you can do:

```
processWolf(porthos.Wolf) 
processWolf(aussie.Wolf)
```

because when you embed `Wolf` into `Dog`, `Dog` gets all the methods `Wolf` has, plus `Dog` has a member called `Wolf`.

Comment: This does not work for me.  The use case is my mongodb code is exactly the same except the object it returns or takes. If go had generics might have worked, as I could have declared some <T>, but no luck in go.  The other option was this, having a base class allowing me to unify the mongo code. In effect it needs to support multiple cases e.g. decoding the objects from the cursor, or performing the updates.  Using .Wolf only passes part of the object. So many patterns need this ability.  I also tried using interface{} - interesting, but still no cigar for decoding the cursor using interface{}.

Comment: Show your code. You can do this with mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

When i originally posted the question I tried to simplify the problem statement, perhaps too much and Mr. Serdar was kind enough to answer the question, but did not help with my problem. After more digging into the lang of gophers, i came across a solution which used interface{} to solve this. I adapted it my mongo code and it is working, though I might say it does not look as simple as with other language passing references around.

```
// FindAll retrieves one object from the collection
func FindAll(collection *mongo.Collection, filter bson.M, resultSet interface{}) error {

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 30*time.Seconds)
    defer cancel()

    cursor, err := collection.Find(ctx, filter)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer cursor.Close(ctx)

    objects := reflect.ValueOf(resultSet).Elem()

    for cursor.Next(ctx) {

        obj := reflect.New(objects.Type().Elem())

        err = cursor.Decode(obj.Interface())

        if err != nil {
            log.Panicln("FindAll:", err.Error())
            // assuming that an interface is out of alignment and need to know ASAP.
        }

        objects = reflect.Append(objects, obj.Elem())
    }

    reflect.ValueOf(resultSet).Elem().Set(objects)

    return nil
}
```

and then call it using

```
    var dogs []Dog
    if err := database.FindAll(houseCollection, bson.M{}, &dogs); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    println(dogs)
```

```
    var dingos []Dingo
    if err := database.FindAll(houseCollection, bson.M{}, &dingos); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    println(dingos)
```

Without Dog and Dingo having to be related with a base class. But I really felt that the designers of Golang made some weird turns that I have yet to understand. Though having fun chasing Gophers.